# Create a Dictionary with conditions

Tags: c#, dictionary, group-by

I have a IEnumerable with this values:[1,2,6,8,10,5,6,9,4,4,2,6,8,2,4,7,9,2,4]
and I want to create a dictionary that group by following this criterion values

1. x between 1 to 3, and counting.
2. x between 4 to 7, and counting.
3. x between 8 and 10, and counted.

I did this to eliminate the duplicate values ​​and counting

```
Dictionary<int, int> childDictionary = childArray.GroupBy(x => x)
                                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                                g => g.Count());
```

the Result:

```
key count
1    1
2    4
4    4
5    1
6    3
7    1
8    2 
9    2
10   1
```

After that, is possible to do the same in the Dictionary, but with many conditions involving the `GroupBy` like:

```
//Bad code
 GroupBy(x>=1 and x<3)
```

for all conditions that I was mentioned early?
the result should be this, assuming it takes a key for each condition

```
key count
1    5
2    9
3    5
```

where:

- 1 is the key for the first condition
- 2 is the key for the second condition
- 3 is the key for the third condition

Comment: Would a `for` statement help?

Comment: `GroupBy(x => x/4)` ?

Comment: If you want to count all numbers between 1 and 3, what should the `key` in your grouping be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a different key in the GroupBy, for example using different int values

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

var items = new int[] {1,2,6,8,10,5,6,9,4,4,2,6,8,2,4,7,9,2,4};

var result = items.GroupBy(x => {
    //x between 1 to 3, and counting.
    if (x >= 1 && x <= 3) return 1;
    //x between 4 to 7, and counting.
    if (x >= 4 && x <= 7) return 2;
    //x between 8 and 10, and counted.
    if (x >= 8 && x <= 10) return 3;
    //else
    return 4;
}).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());


foreach (var kv in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

result:

```
Key = 1, Value = 5
Key = 2, Value = 9
Key = 3, Value = 5
```

demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wIAlrj